# Java indexOf returns false for unfound string?

Tags: java

I need to know whether in Java does the `indexOf()` method return `false` or `void` for an unfound string? or does it return an index `int` of 0?

Comment: I had tried google and searching through API's but none told me so I came here as a semi-last-resort for this question

Comment: If you use an IDE, you can <ctrl>+<click> on a method like indexOf to see the code and the Javadoc.

Answer (score 30):

It'll return -1 (hint: try it)

As in the [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)

Comment: "Try it" isn't particularly definitive - but "read the docs" is :)

Comment: Assuming the docs are correct :-) I take your point, however.

Comment: I downvoted for "hint: try it". That's in no way constructive or imperative to the question at hand.

Comment: You’ll note the actual answer in the above

Answer (score 13):

The [Java API docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) contain this answer. the `indexOf` methods on a `String` return -1 if the character is not found.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [signature](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)). It says `int`, so an integer is returned. To return another type (void or boolean) the signature would be different.

Comment: I'm guessing he is coming from the PHP world, where the "int" datatype is "only a guideline" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Only [PHP's str_pos](http://php.net/str_pos) is weird enough to return 0/false when the index isn't found.  Most consider the PHP version to be a bad implementation.

```
int strpos  ( string $haystack  , mixed $needle  [, int $offset= 0  ] )

//Returns the position as an integer. If needle  is not found, strpos()
// will return boolean  FALSE.

/*
  Warning
  function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which
  evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on Booleans for more
  information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.
*/
```

Comment: What I don't get is the... ok so if the string starts with the keyword you are looking for, it will return 0, but if doesn't find what you are looking for, it might also return 0? WT?

Comment: Although 0 == false, 0 !== false. But indeed, that's one of the worse design decisions in PHP's built-in functions (as in: bites me in the butt every so often).

Comment: The OP asked about Java and the respondent talks about PHP. Please explain how comments on PHP are relevant to a discussion of Java issues...

Comment: The OP asked if indexOf might return anything other than an integer. All decent programming languages I know of return an integer. However, in order to ask this question one likely has to have come from somewhere that returned something other that an integer. As such there was a good chance the OP came from the PHP world and had encountered this issue due to their complicated implementation. This answer is therefore here to calm any fears, and help illustrate (for many) how they may have been led astray in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You mean Javascript? It returns -1.

Comment: No, he means Java, hence the phrase 'in Java', rather than 'in Javascript'

Comment: It is a very basic question, so his knowledge is very limited. I heard people refering to Javasctipt as Java when they are begginers. Now he knows the answer for two different questions ;)